# Geometry Nodes - Creating a path of edges through a point domain without any overlap

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry

Hoping someone can help. I'm trying to create a geonodes setup where I distribute points on a mesh, and then connect a series of edges between them which will be converted to curves and used for animation. The issue however is that I do not want any of the edges to overlap, like a railway track for example (that is not the specific use case but just an example)

The screenshot below is where I got to before I realised that I needed the paths not to overlap. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

[image]